# Why does eUICC Manager get NO_SUCH_ELEMENT aka errcode 3?

Tags: esim

I was trying to port eUICC into my phone (I used Google LPA called SIM Manager and other stuff from the same system but other model). I am using Motorola Edge 30 Ultra and used that kit from Moto X40 which natively supports eSIM. I also tried porting the eUICC function from OnePlus 11 to OnePlus 8 and the same error occurred.

It seems status 3 was an error `NO_SUCH_ELEMENT`, which means no AID was found on the eUICC. But my card had successfully downloaded the profile on Truphone LPA for desktop, and my phone detected the profile and works.

But why does this error occur? Any idea? Permission granted, hardware I think it must be there for AID to be shown. And I don't know if HAL or else could be an error or not. Should I define if I am using an eUICC chip in the SIM (UICC) style and in the SIM slot?

Logs below：

```
2023-10-14 13:22:14.534  3860-3860  EuiccCardController     com.android.phone                    E  
getEuiccChallenge callback onException: 
com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.EuiccCardException: Cannot send APDU.
    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.EuiccPort.lambda$sendApdu$50(EuiccPort.java:1159)
    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.EuiccPort.$r8$lambda$8x9Mw_LfktrBXDaDFYF0Xl8vpps(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.EuiccPort$$ExternalSyntheticLambda52.handleException(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.EuiccPort$1.onException(EuiccPort.java:1224)
    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.apdu.ApduSender$1.onResult(ApduSender.java:138)
    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.apdu.ApduSender$1.onResult(ApduSender.java:127)
    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.async.AsyncMessageInvocation.handleMessage(AsyncMessageInvocation.java:57)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:238)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:357)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8088)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:957)
Caused by: com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.apdu.ApduException: Failed to open logical channel opened for AID: A0000005591010FFFFFFFF8900000100, with status: 3 (apduStatus=0)
    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.apdu.ApduSender$1.onResult(ApduSender.java:138) 
    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.apdu.ApduSender$1.onResult(ApduSender.java:127) 
    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.async.AsyncMessageInvocation.handleMessage(AsyncMessageInvocation.java:57) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:238) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:357) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8088) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:957) 

2023-10-14 13:22:18.904  3860-3860  EuiccCardController     com.android.phone                    E  
getEuiccChallenge callback onException: 
    com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.EuiccCardException: Cannot send APDU.
    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.EuiccPort.lambda$sendApdu$50(EuiccPort.java:1159)
    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.EuiccPort.$r8$lambda$8x9Mw_LfktrBXDaDFYF0Xl8vpps(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.EuiccPort$$ExternalSyntheticLambda52.handleException(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.EuiccPort$1.onException(EuiccPort.java:1224)
    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.apdu.ApduSender$1.onResult(ApduSender.java:138)
    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.apdu.ApduSender$1.onResult(ApduSender.java:127)
    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.async.AsyncMessageInvocation.handleMessage(AsyncMessageInvocation.java:57)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:238)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:357)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8088)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:957)
Caused by: com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.apdu.ApduException: Failed to open logical channel opened for AID: A0000005591010FFFFFFFF8900000100, with status: 3 (apduStatus=0)
    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.apdu.ApduSender$1.onResult(ApduSender.java:138) 
    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.apdu.ApduSender$1.onResult(ApduSender.java:127) 
    at com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.euicc.async.AsyncMessageInvocation.handleMessage(AsyncMessageInvocation.java:57) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:238) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:357) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8088) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:957)
```

Tried:

- An eSIM chip sorted on UICC base.
- `com.google.android.euicc` package installed and granted permission.
- Also ported an eUICC partner for slot mapping.

Expected eUICC management to work and could download or delete a profile, but now the download is stuck there and cannot send APDU to the log again and again.